# Show <td> border in html only when there's a data in HTML using jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like this in HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">  
    <thead>  
        <tr>  
            <th>Tag</th> 
            <th>Time Code</th>  
        </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody>  
        <tr>  
            <td>{{ choice.tag1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.time_code1 }}</td>                    
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>{{ choice.tag2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.time_code2 }}</td>                    
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>{{ choice.tag3 }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.time_code3 }}</td>                    
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>{{ choice.tag4 }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.time_code4 }}</td>                    
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>{{ choice.tag5 }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.time_code5 }}</td>                    
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>{{ choice.tag6 }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.time_code6 }}</td>                    
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>{{ choice.tag7 }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.time_code7 }}</td>                    
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>{{ choice.tag8 }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.time_code8 }}</td>                    
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>{{ choice.tag9 }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.time_code9 }}</td>                    
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>{{ choice.tag10 }}</td>
            <td>{{ choice.time_code10 }}</td>                   
        </tr>  
    </tbody>  
</table>
```

The variable that I passed using `{{}}` most of the times are empty. Even if's it empty td is shown. I don't cut off the space and don't show any td's if they are empty. For example sometimes I may have data up to 3rd td only thus I want to show only up to 3rd td. Is this possible using jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: what templating system are you using? (refering to the `{{}}` calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this may be it will you help you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".table tbody td").each(function(){
    if($(this).html()=="")
      {
       $(this).hide();
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Don't show comma if variable is empty for this:
{{ choice.tag1 }}, {{ choice.tag2 }}, {{ choice.tag3 }}

Comment: How can I do this? It's also under table tbody td

Comment: Posted another question for this: please answer::
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761626/show-comma-in-html-only-if-the-variable-has-value-using-jquery?noredirect=1#comment22401582_15761626

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
{% if(!empty{choice.time_code1 }) %}
<tr>  
    <td>{{ choice.tag1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ choice.time_code1 }}</td>                    
</tr>
{% end:if %}
```

Comment: Isn't it `{% if condition %} […] {% endif %}` in [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide td if they are empty and entire tr if both td are empty try this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".table tbody tr").each(function(){
     var empty = true;
     $(this).find("td").each(function(){
        if ($(this).html()=="")
           $(this).hide();
        else
           empty = false;
     });
     if (empty){
        $(this).hide();
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Or you could run a for loop in javascript